# How I Update pandas using spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I try to convert a datastucture i get from pandas to an array using .to_numpy but my pandas version is too old. Trying to update it writing: conda install -c anaconda pandas inside anaconda prompt resolves in this issue: ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::tqdm-4.50.2-py_0'. CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\domyb\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe Running conda clean --packages may resolve your problem. Attempting to roll back.

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\domyb\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe Running conda clean --packages may resolve your problem. Any idea?

Comment: did you try running `conda clean --packages`?

Comment: it suggests me this option, but i was afraid of something and i asked here first. what is the purpose of this command?

Comment: @jakub still get the error sir

Comment: For anyone with same issue, nothing i read elsewhere worked. I had to disinstall and reinstall anaconda to anewer version.